# Change WooCommerce Order status from frontend form submitted data

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to have a form on the front end of the site asking for the WooCommerce Order Number and phone number.

Once the user submitted the details, it'll check for orders and if the data matched then it'll change the order status from processing to complete. If not, then it'll show an error message.

I have followed [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70517676/woocommerce-order-status-update-from-select-from-frontend) but this is not quite what I am looking at.

Also, this code is applicable on the [My Account page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56066431/allow-customer-to-change-the-order-status-in-woocommerce-my-account). But I want the form to be public.

I tried using Contact Form 7 to get the data also [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73161171/woocommerce-change-order-status-to-processing-when-sending-contact-form-7). But with no success.

Any direction you guys can provide me so that I'll move ahead from there?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I published a plugin who does exactly what you need. But form is loaded in the client details order page. May be it could help you:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7orderstatusswitcher/